# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.TimeSpan Subtract(System.DateTime)' method

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I try to select records in database in 60 days 30 days 20 days differents in current date.

Please see this query in below.

```
 var uploads = (
                from files in _fileuploadRepository.Table
                join product in _productRepository.Table on files.Event equals product.Id
                where
                    (
                product.EventDate != null &&
                    (product.EventDate.Subtract(DateTime.Now).Days <= 60 && product.EventDate.Subtract(DateTime.Now).Days >= 60) ||
                    (product.EventDate.Subtract(DateTime.Now).Days <= 30 && product.EventDate.Subtract(DateTime.Now).Days >= 30) ||
                    (product.EventDate.Subtract(DateTime.Now).Days <= 20 && product.EventDate.Subtract(DateTime.Now).Days >= 20))
                    &&
                files.IsSkiped == false
                select files;
            ).ToList();
```

But a error occurred this query.

[image]

I am clueless. Please Help.

Comment: Do you calculations outside of the lambda statement.  When it's inside the lambda like you're using it, you're trying have EntityFramework do the calculation when it's not meant to do so.

Comment: So LINQ to SQL won't "translate" an expression like `product.EventDate.Subtract(DateTime.Now)`. In C# an alternative notation is `product.EventDate - DateTime.Now` where one uses [an overload of the minus (`-`) operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1905yhe2.aspx). Does anyone know if _that_ will work with LINQ to SQL? After all, subtraction of dates is also possible in SQL dialects.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen For EF you can use EntityFunctions.DiffDays

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The simplest approach is to work out the bounds *before* you perform the query:

```
// Only evaluate DateTime.Now once for consistency. You might want DateTime.Today instead.
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
DateTime nowPlus60Days = now.AddDays(60);
DateTime nowPlus30Days = now.AddDays(30);
DateTime nowPlus20Days = now.AddDays(20);

var query = ...
            where product.EventDate <= nowPlus60Days
            ...
```

Note that your current query doesn't even really make sense, as each "or"'d clause is stating that the given computation is both less than or equal to a value *and* greater than or equal to the same value. If you want simple "equal to" then use that. If not, it's not clear what you *are* trying to do.

If you're trying to bucket the values into "less than 20", "20-30", "30-60", "more than 60" you'll need to use grouping of some form.

Answer (score 64):

You could use the `EntityFunctions.DiffDays` method

```
EntityFunctions.DiffDays(product.EventDate, DateTime.Now) //this will return the difference in days
```

**UPDATE**

EntityFunctions is now obsolete so you should use DBFunctions instead.

```
System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.DiffDays(product.EventDate, DateTime.Now)
```

Comment: EntityFunctions is now Obsolete: use System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions instead.

Answer (score 5):

This should work:

```
using System.Data.Entity.SqlServer;

where (int)SqlFunctions.DateDiff("day", product.EventDate, DateTime.Now) <= 60
```

Answer (score 3):

To add on to scartag's answer,

The [MSDN documentation for DbFunctions.DiffDays](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbfunctions.diffdays%28v=vs.113%29.aspx#M:System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.DiffDays%28System.Nullable%7BSystem.DateTime%7D,System.Nullable%7BSystem.DateTime%7D%29) doesn't directly mention whether and when the value returned by DiffDays() will be negative, so I thought I'd provide that information here:

The result will be negative when the argument 1 date is larger than (i.e. in the future relative to) the argument 2 date.

For example, given a table `Deliveries` with a non-null field `ScheduledDeliveryDate` that can have values both in the past and in the future relative to the current date, this query will get all records with a delivery date/time within 2 days of the current date/time (both past and future):

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
var results = from d in Deliveries
    where (DbFunctions.DiffDays(d.ScheduledDeliveryDate, now) < 2
        && DbFunctions.DiffDays(d.ScheduledDeliveryDate, now) > -2)
    select d;
```

Answer (score 0):

Count Total

```
 var CountDay = db.YourTable.Where(s => s.Condition1 == 1 && s.Condition2 == false && DbFunctions.DiffDays(s.YourDate, DateTime.Now) > 0).Count().ToString();
```