# Using DbFunctions.TruncateDate and still have error: **The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities.**

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6

I am getting an error:
**The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities.**

I have a code where I have tried to follow the answers of other two other posts: [LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.TimeSpan Subtract(System.DateTime)' method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15264319/linq-to-entities-does-not-recognize-the-method-system-timespan-subtractsystem) and [Linq To Sql compare Time only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21287730/linq-to-sql-compare-time-only)

Also this method is executed by many threads in parallel.

```
public List<Element> GetResults()
{
    List<Element> elements = new List<Element>();

   try {

    using (DbContext context = new EntitiesContext())
    {

    DateTime dateTimeNow = DateTime.Now;
    TimeSpan timeSpanNow = DateTime.Now.TimeSpan;      
    elements = context.Elements.
                          // Some other Includes
                          //Element has a field System.DateTime DateTime
                          .Include(_ => _.DateTime)              
                          .Where(o => DbFunctions.TruncateDate(o.DateTime.Date) == dateTimeNow 
&& DbFunctions.CreateTime(o.DateTime.Hour, o.DateTime.Minute, o.DateTime.Second) <= timeSpanNow))
.ToList();


    }
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    //logging
} 

return elements;
    }
```

Comment: `DbFunctions.TruncateDate(o.DateTime.Date)` should be `DbFunctions.TruncateTime(o.DateTime)`

Comment: @Evk I will try it, thanks a lot.

Comment: Ok @Evk, worked, post the answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, there is no such thing as `DbFunctions.TruncateDate`, as far as I know. I assume that's just a typo and you meant `DbFuctions.TruncateTime`.

Then, you are using `DbFunctions.TruncateTime` because EF doesn't understand how to translate `someDateTime.Date` to SQL. By doing

```
DbFunctions.TruncateDate(o.DateTime.Date)
```

you are still using the same thing which EF doesn't understand, so you need to get rid of that `Date`:

```
DbFunctions.TruncateDate(o.DateTime)
```